# Calling an environment using token contcats (expl3) makes some internal contents show up at the end of document

Tags: environments, expl3, latex3

I need to dynamically apply an environment (or possibly a series of nested environments)on some text using expl3 (latex3) commands. However, the environment behaves differently when concatenate a series of environment related tokens using expl3, in compare to when I use it normally by embedding the text. Using expl3, any content inside the environment which comes after the passed body content (that is `+b`), appears at the end of document, instead of appearing next to the passed body content.

What is the problem?

The MWE below shows the problem.
[image: Result of MWE]

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\RequirePackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{ +b}{
        \tl_set:Nn \l_myenv_body_tl {#1}

    <myenv~begins>~\use:n  \l_myenv_body_tl
    <This~should~appear~before~myenv~ending.>
}{ <myenv~ends~here.>}
 
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

    First line.
    
    \vspace \medskipamount

    % An environment by normal approach
    \begin{myenv}
        Some text for the regular body.
    \end{myenv}

    \vspace \medskipamount  

    Second line.

    \vspace \medskipamount
    
    % An environment created using Expl3
    \ExplSyntaxOn

    \tl_set:Nn \l_body_tl {Some~text~for~the~body.}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_beginings_tl {\begin{myenv} }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_endings_tl {\end{myenv}}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_total_tl {}   
    
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_total_tl {\l_beginings_tl} 
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_total_tl {\l_body_tl} 
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_total_tl {\l_endings_tl} 

    \use:n {\l_total_tl}    
 
    \ExplSyntaxOff


    \vspace \medskipamount
    
    Third line.
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\tl_put_right:NV` instead to expand `\l_endings_tl`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I checked again and the image is the original to the code, just with my annotations. I am using Tex live 2022 Lualatex (if this can make a difference).

Comment: @Skillmon, Thanks! it helped me in the actual solution.

Comment: Sorry should I have thought of luatex, we usually assume pdftex unless a different engine mntioned:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using  a `b` argument so that needs to see a literal `\end{myenv}` it can not be hidden behind a macro (you would see the same if you used `\def\foo{\end{myenv}}` the fact you used `expl3` not really related to the issue.

Simpler non `expl3` example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{ +b}{
    <myenv~begins>
        #1
    <This~should~appear~before~myenv~ending.>
}{ <myenv~ends~here.>}
 

\def\fooA{\begin{myenv}}
\def\fooB{\end{myenv}}



\begin{document}

    First line.

    \begin{myenv}
      abc
    \end{myenv}

    Second line.

\fooA
  xyz
\fooB

    Third line.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clearing that. It also show the solution.